# ProjectM "Easter Egg Parameter" in config.inp?

Tags: configuration

What does

```
Easter Egg Parameter = 1
```

Do in `~/.config/projectM/config.inp`? I didn't put it there. Just wondering.

Answer (score 0):

On non-Windows platforms, it controls the width of [the simili-Gaussian curve](https://github.com/projectM-visualizer/projectm/blob/99dccdf101619c64929bbac6097c6923d2fe7873/src/libprojectM/RandomNumberGenerators.hpp#L36) which is used to [introduce some randomness in the preset duration](https://github.com/projectM-visualizer/projectm/blob/6240b9d14a2efa9a5a5a4bdbf33406e51ad53c9e/src/libprojectM/TimeKeeper.cpp#L109).